# how to add a sort by on boolean values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following:

```
items=Queryable.where("val ilike '%#{term}%' and metro_area_id=?", metro_area_id).limit(limit).offset(offset).order('liked_count desc')
```

and would like to add two conditionals to my sort.

We'll probably be moving this to a hosted query service but need to get this logic running.

If has_images=true and has_notes=true, it sorts above liked_count. Then if has_images=true, then has_notes=true. Such that:

```
Queryable:   
\-has_images==true && has_notes==true, sort by liked count   
\-has_images==true && has_notes==false, sort by liked count  
\-has_images==false && has_notes==true, sort by liked_count
```

How would I adjust the Rails query to achieve this?

Comment: Does `order(has_images: :desc, has_notes: :desc, liked_count: :desc)` work?

Comment: thx @AbM I'm pretty sure that this is going to work. I have to write up a specs to be sure but just doing it code looks like it does. thx